# angular.js: How to use templates and JSON for building a SPA

Tags: javascript, html, json, angularjs

I'm using angular.js to create a SPA. I need your advise which technique I have to use for showing the informations/articles.

My **index.html** looks like this:

```
<body>
    <header id="navigation">
        <nav id="main">
            <ul>
                <li id="login"><button class="btn">Login</button></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <main>

    </main>
    <footer>
        <p>Some text</p>
    </footer>
</body>
```

At the beginning this HTML (using the directive angucomplete-alt) should be shown in the main-container:

**autocomplete-search-template.html:**

```
<div>Any content</div>
<div id="searching" ng-controller='search'>
    <div angucomplete-alt id="s1" selected-object="select" remote-url="search.php?q=" remote-url-data-field="results" title-field="title" description-field="description"></div>
</div>
```

When the user is searching for an article the following controller is used:

**controller:**

```
app.controller('search', ['$scope', '$http',
    function s1($scope, $http) {

        $scope.select = function(selected) {
            if (selected) {
                /* Article has been chosen */
            }
        };

    }
]);
```

The article-template.html looks like this and should be inserted into the main-container, after the user has selected an article in the search (angucomplete-alt:

**article-template.html:**

```
<article>
    <header>{{title}}</header>
    <div>{{content}}</div>
</article>
```

Now I don't know how I should put this parts together and therefore I need your help.

1. How do I put these templates together? (a) Do I have to use routing or is there another technique? If I have to use routing, then I don't know how to get from the search-result to the article-display as it is no href-link... (b) Or would it be better to use ng-include (c) Or another option?
2. Where (and when) do I get the article informations? I think I have to use a http-post request to get a JSON-array which will be used to fill the placeholders of article-template.html. So I thought of doing a request in the `$scope.select`. But there is still my problem of merging everything together

**Update Routing:**

```
app.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
    .when('/search', {
        templateUrl: 'autocomplete-search-template.html',
        controller: 'search'
    })
    .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/search'
    });
});
```

This is working to show the autocomplete-search-template.html at the frontpage. But I don't know how to route for the results of the angucomplete-alt search.

Comment: Yes you would need routing from your content description. Go through the tutorial  on angular documentation site step by step. Will help get started at least

Comment: i personally prefer ui-router, but the angular website has decent tutorial to get you going

Comment: could you please give me an example how to do the routing with the above code? I really don't know how to do that with the angucomplete-alt directive. This is my real problem. How do I have to route after the article has been chosen?

Comment: I added the routing at the post. But as I said, I don't know how to route for the results of the search.

Comment: there is a near identical case to yours in the examples for the `angucomplete-alt` package, have you tried replicating that?

Comment: If you are talking about Example 5, then yes. I tried to do this. And so far it is working, as I receive the JSON-array and I can show the results. After I select an item, I don't know how to go on. See the 'controller' in the post. How do I get from this selection to the 'template-routing'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With [Angular ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router) you can use a nested view for your search result.

To get your data before the view is loaded you can use `resolve` to get the data from server. Then you can inject the resolved promise into you controller and use the returned data in your nested view.

With `$state.go('search.article', {foundArticle: $scope.selectedPerson});` you can pass the selected item from `angucomplete` to the nested view.

To make the paramter passing work you need to add the following to the nested view:

```
$stateProvider.state('search.article', {
    ...
    params:{foundArticle:null},
    controller: function ($scope, $stateParams) {
        $scope.article = $stateParams.foundArticle;
    }
}
```

For an example of the usage see the demo below (code not working here on SO - 'operation is insecure' issue. Don't know how to fix.) and here at [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/awolf2904/cy9othy7/).

The code could be improved at the following points:

- Using a service for getting the data.
- If your articles are large you probably need to do another resolve at transition to the article and load at pageload only the needed data. The demo loads everything at the beginning.

```js
angular.module('myApp', ['ui.router', 'angucomplete-alt'])
    .controller('search', function ($scope, $state, searchData) {
        
    //console.log(searchData.data); 
    $scope.people = searchData.data;
     
    // static dummy data below
    /*$scope.people = [
         {firstName: "Susan", surname: "Rowland", twitter: "@susanrowland", pic: "http://lorempixel.com/100/100/people/1/", content: 'text for Susan'},
      {firstName: "Alan", surname: "Partridge", twitter: "@alangpartridge", pic: "http://lorempixel.com/100/100/people/3/", content: 'text for Alan'},
      {firstName: "Annie", surname: "Rowland", twitter: "@anklesannie", pic: "http://lorempixel.com/100/100/people/6/", content: 'text for Annie'}
    ];*/
        
    $scope.select = function(selected) {
            if (selected) {
                console.log(selected, $state);
                /* Article has been chosen */
                $scope.selectedPerson = selected; // same as two-way binding
                $state.go('search.article', {foundArticle: $scope.selectedPerson});
            }
        };
})
.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    //
    // For any unmatched url, redirect to /state1
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/search");
    //
    // Now set up the states
    $stateProvider.state('search', {
        url: "/search",
        resolve: {
            searchData: function ($http) {
                return $http.jsonp('http://www.mocky.io/v2/554f135e539c140e02858ff7/?callback=JSON_CALLBACK');
            }
        },
        templateUrl: "partials/search.html",
        controller: 'search'
    })
        .state('search.article', {
        url: "/article",
        params:{foundArticle:null},
        templateUrl: "partials/search.article.html",
        controller: function ($scope, $stateParams) {
            $scope.article = $stateParams.foundArticle;
        }
    })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.2.14/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ghiden/angucomplete-alt/master/dist/angucomplete-alt.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/ng-template" id="partials/search.html">
    <!-- partials/state1.html -->
    <h1>Search users (e.g. Rowland)</h1>
    <hr/>
    <!--<a ui-sref="state1.list">Show List</a>-->
    <div angucomplete-alt id="ex2" placeholder="Search people" pause="300" selected-object="select" local-data="people" search-fields="firstName,surname" title-field="firstName,surname" description-field="twitter" image-field="pic" minlength="1" input-class="form-control form-control-small" match-class="highlight">
    </div>
        <div class="result">
            <div class="" ng-show="selectedPerson" >
                You selected <span class="bold-span">{{selectedPerson.originalObject.firstName}} {{selectedPerson.originalObject.surname}}</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    <div ui-view></div>
</script>

<script type="text/ng-template" id="partials/search.article.html">
    <h3>Found article</h3>
    <article>
    <header>{{article.title}}</header>
    <div>
        <p>{{article.originalObject.content}}</p>
        <pre>{{article | json}}</pre></div>
</article>
</script>

<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ui-view=""></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for that great answer. As I just need to display the article, I want to "replace" the search-form with the article-template. This article-template already exists for direct display with the state `url: "/chapter/:article_title". So would it be possible to use the same template for displaying the article selected by the search? Hope I could explain, what I mean...